# How to redirect non www to www and http to https?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, iis

I have created a small web app with react nodejs. I have hosted on the IIS web server. I want to redirect the non-www URL to www and HTTP to HTTPS. I have used below the web.config file for redirection

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  
    <system.webServer>  
        <rewrite>  
            <rules>  
<rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">  
                    <match url=".*" />  
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">  
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />  
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />  
                    </conditions>  
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />  
                </rule>  

            
            <rule name="httptohttps" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="non-wwwtowww" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
           
            </rules>  
        </rewrite>  
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

The above code works correctly for the landing page but for other pages HTTPS not working. I have already purchased an SSL certificate.

If I directly opened the example.com/xyz page then the non-secure page opened means http://example.com/xyz page opened.

if I removed s and www from URL mean https://www.example.com/xyz then routing not performed.

I want to route all pages of my web app to HTTPS and www.

I have written some code on the server-side(node js)

```
//301 redirection http to https and non-www to www

 const redirectionFilter = function (req, res, next) {
   const theDate = new Date();
   const receivedUrl = `${req.protocol}:\/\/${req.hostname}:${port}${req.url}`;

   if (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') === 'http') {
     const redirectTo = `https:\/\/${req.hostname}${req.url}`;
     console.log(`${theDate} Redirecting ${receivedUrl} --> ${redirectTo}`);
     res.redirect(301, redirectTo);
   } else {
     next();
   }

 };

/**
 * Apply redirection filter to all requests
 */
app.get('/*', redirectionFilter);


 app.use((req, res, next) => {
   const host = req.header('host');
   if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
       next();
   } else {
       res.redirect(301, `${req.protocol}://www.${host}${req.url}`);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule, merge them into one and use the logicalGrouping for the conditions and set it to Any which would be the equivalent of an "OR".

```
<rule name="Force WWW and HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
   </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.zzz.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, @samwu it's working. The above rule also works for SEO google search. After adding the above rule SEO shows without HTTPS pages on google serach.

Comment: Try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed information.